# is it possible to set multiple color in UILabel?

Tags: iphone, uilabel

Quote from Jason Coco
it not possible to set multiple in UILabel... but

how to do like this?

any idea?

[image]

is it possible to set mix color in UILabel

example   "TEST"
can i set  E  to red color and another to white color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, sadly this is not possible with UILabel. You can google some alternatives and the iPad will have NSAttributedString, but with UILabel the entire string has to be one font/color.

Comment: could you please answer me another question?

Comment: @RAGOpoR - They are almost certainly using images, not UILabels.

Comment: Thanks for you advise Jason Coco

Answer (score 11):

[FontLabel](http://github.com/zynga/FontLabel) is a drop-in replacement for UILabel that can take an attributed string as its text.  That will allow you use multiple colors and fonts in a single label.

Answer (score 7):

[TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) is a drop-in replacement for UILabel that's a lot more lightweight and simple than other libraries like [FontLabel](http://github.com/zynga/FontLabel), for instance. All you would need to do is set an NSAttributedString as the text for that label.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in iOS 5 but iOS 6 supports it. As you can see in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797

UILabel gain the attributedText property with iOS6, next to UILabel a lot of other UI elements use NSAttributedText too.