# Displaying multi colored string with MonoTouch. Three20, Nimbus or UIWebView?

Tags: c#, ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, uilabel

I want to draw a score string where the latest change is another color like
1-0 and the "1" number should be red. According to various posts I could do this with `UIWebView` or using Three20 or Nimbus.

`UIWebView` seems like a tempting solution but I would think it would strain the device showing 5-10 webviews in a `UITableView`?

Anyone done this with MonoTouch? From my Googling the bindings against Three20 isn't the easiest to setup and I didn't see anyone had done the bindings against Nimbus. The class I would like to use is this one: 
http://docs.nimbuskit.info/_n_i_attributed_label_8m_source.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage seems simple. Perhaps using `NSAttributedString` would be enough ?

See 
[How do you use NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring) for an Objective-C sample. From a quick look translating this to C# should not be hard (compared to using 3rd parties libraries).

Comment: I need to show the string in a UILabel, and from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452356/is-it-possible-to-set-multiple-color-in-uilabel it seems that is not possible without another set of 3rd party labels that have no MonoTouch bindings :-/

Comment: IMHO it's likely easier to create your own *managed* control (more control, easier build steps...) on top of `NSAttributedString` than to wrap an existing library. OTOH you can use `btouch` to create your own binding library for the 3rd party control that best fits your need. The nice things about MonoTouch is that you have both options available to you :-)

Comment: Thanks, I like using others proved-to-work code so will have a look at btouch :-)

Comment: Here are the bindings for Nimbus. The attribute label bindings will eventually be added. https://github.com/theonlylawislove/MonoTouch.Nimbus