# How to set different fonts in table view detail text label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

In my table view with cell style value1 , in text label i displayed date&time. in detailstext label I displayed `**Title:-Comments**`,

all the titles and comments not in same length.

![enter image description here][1]
Now i need to display **title with one color,font and comments with other color and font** what i need to do

Comment: [cell.textLabel  setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[cell.textLabel  setFont:[UIFont font....]];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452356/is-it-possible-to-set-multiple-color-in-uilabel)

Comment: @sunajledif I think the OP wants two different fonts in one `UILabel`

Comment: @alanduncan oops. yes. sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set all your attributes you require in the text label when the cell is created:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
  static NSString *kCellId = @"CellId";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellId];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellId];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"CenturyGothic-Bold" size:17];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:53/255.0 green:55/255.0 blue:53/255.0 alpha:1];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(73/255.0) green:(14/255.0) blue:(111/255.0) alpha:1];
  }

  id obj = [filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  cell.textLabel.text = [obj valueForKey:@"title"];

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: the i want two different fonts in one UILabel

Comment: You can't do that with a regular UILabel. You either use two labels or you have to use CoreText.

Comment: You need to subclass UILabel. And also you need to use CoreText & NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem.

You can create a custom `UITableViewCell` and layout three separate `UILabel` instances that you style however you like; or, you can create a custom `UITableViewCell` and use a drop-in replacement for `UILabel` that allows you to employ `NSAttributedString`.  The first solution will be more straightforward.