# Two different colors inside an UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I have an UITextField where the initial text is "username.mysite.com". The default color (Black) is set.

I would like to have "username" with a different color like gray. Is it possible?

User can click the "Clear Button", than the placeholder is "url".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done with a UITextField directly.  Your basic two options are:

1. Use a `UIWebView` masquerading as a text field.  This is easy, but is a sledge hammer and can incur performance penalties in certain use cases.
2. Use [Core Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html) to display a duly configured NSAttributedString.  Though the link appears to be for Mac OS, Core Text exists on iOS too.  The framework is very powerful but has a steep learning curve and doesn't support editable text out of the box.  There are, however, various open source libraries that might of help getting started (e.g. [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText). [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the colour of placeholder, by accessing following private property, it will show warning to you, but it will be going to work very well.

```
[aTextField setValue:[UIColor yellowColor] 
            forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

There is another way also present for doing this, you can override drawPlaceholderInRect method with your custom implementation.

Comment: Hi RIP, I want to change the color of property text not place holder. And the color is just for the part "username" not the entire text.

Comment: i think that is not possible directly, you can check following thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452356/is-it-possible-to-set-multiple-color-in-uilabel

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` has an `attributedText` property, that can be set to any `NSAttributedString` with any colors you like. For example:

```swift
// Create a string:
let attribString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "username.mysite.com")

// Set the grey color to the "username" portion of the string (the black color is the default for the rest):
attribString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.gray, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 8))

// Set the attributed string to your text field:
textField.attributedText = attribString
```